# Sequence of WPF control initialization - IsEnabled

Tags: c#, wpf, initialization

I'm looking at a problem where I'm getting ValueChanged events on a slider right off the bat when I start my program, before my code is fully initialized and ready to process them.

The XAML for the slider is

```
    <Slider Name="ZoomSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Left"    Margin="930,191,0,0"    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Width="212" Height="30" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="2"  Maximum="200"
 Minimum="12"  IsEnabled="False" Value="50"  ValueChanged="ZoomSlider_ValueChanged"  />
```

... Notice that IsEnabled is set to False.

But in the event handler, if I interrogate the state of the control it returns true . . .

```
private void ZoomSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    var slider = sender as Slider;
    bool b = ZoomSlider.IsEnabled;  // says TRUE!
    double value = slider.Value;   // retrieve value
    GlobalZoom = value / 50;
}
```

The event is called as soon as *InitializeComponent()* is called in my main window initialization code, but by the time it returns from that call IsEnabled returns false.  In fact if I do an F11 and try to step into the *InitializeComponent()* call it immediately goes to the ValueChanged event handler.

```
 . . . 
    InitializeComponent();
    bool b = ZoomSlider.IsEnabled;  // says FALSE!
 . . .
```

So I'm confused.  Why is it ever true and firing events, if I have it set to false in the XAML?

**EDIT:**  In the original version of my post I was setting the  IsEnabled="False" **after** assigning the handler in the XAML and some people thought that this was causing the problem due to XAML allegedly being sensitive to order-of-evaluation, unlike XML.  So I switched the order as seen above, and it makes no difference in the problem.

Comment: As specified in an answer, moving the IsEnabled attribute before the ValueChanged attribute resolves this. However, what is is that you are trying to achieve? Do you want to set the GlobalZoom value to a default value if the slider is disabled?

Comment: No, I was going to enable it after the rest of the system was initialized.    But according to the XML specification attribute order shouldn't matter (and infact there are some editors that automatically re-order attributes alphabetically) so why would changing the order here matter?

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `IsEnabled="False"` before `Maximum="200"`
 assignment. There is a sort of order of assignment in XAML not XML.

> Yes order can matter. Consider that XAML reading involves the creation of objects and the assignment of values to the properties of these objects. Its not possible to assign property values at the same time, clearly one property is going to be assigned followed by another and then another until all properties are assigned.

Update:

`Value` is a wrapping property of `RangeBase.Value` dependency property
which is registered with `RangeBase.OnValueChanged` event handler.

As you can see it attached with `RangeBase.OnValueChanged` event handler so `IsEnabled` does not effect on this event handler call.

I'll suggest you to move you event handler assignment into your class constructor after initialization.

Setting `Maximum` or `Minimum` properties is [coercing](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/RangeBase.cs,0a44a746c83967ce,references) `Value` property so value change event handler is called.

Comment: I didn't think the order of the attributes mattered in XML.   [link](http://www.w3.org/XML/Datamodel.html)  Could you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: The order of defining properties values in xaml does not affect behavior. If it does it would be a pain to troubleshoot problems like this.

Comment: I changed the order anyway (see my edit in the OP) but it made no difference in the problem.

Comment: @user316117 I have edited my answer so put the it before `Value` assignment so the `IsEnabled` is assigned when event handler is called

Comment: OK, I moved it before the "Value" statement; still no change.

Comment: @user316117 Sorry, I have just noticed that you are using `ZoomSlider.IsEnabled` in your handler, its not initialized at that moment so please use `slider.IsEnabled`.

Comment: ZoomSlider is the name of the slider (class Slider) and when the handler gets called it is fully initialized (because its being called after InitializeComponent().  In the debugger all the values for slider and ZoomSlider are identical.  If it wasn't initialized I would be getting NullReference exceptions.

Comment: @user316117 sorry my fault, you are right, the problem was that maximum and minimum property are normalizing value so thay are calling value changed as well please move IsEnabled before them

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean flags to keep the thing simple:

```
privat bool initializing = false;

public MainWindows()
{
    initializing = true;
    InitializeComponent();
    initializing = false;
}

private void ZoomSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    if ( initializing )
        return;

   //Normal flow
}
```

Comment: Yes, obviously that will work, but it doesn't answer the question of why the event handler is being called even with IsEnabled set to false.

Comment: Whenever you assign  Minimum and/or  Value you will get this event fired as this will affect its current value. No matter what IsEnabled value you set.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it.  I moved Minimum and Value into the code-behind after my initialization was complete and the handler only gets called when I set them there.  But Maximum doesn't matter - the handler does not get called for that, even if I leave it in the XAML.   What's different about Maximum?  Anyway, thanks, that was the problem.

Comment: Contrary to Minimum, Maximum can't set a value, but it does prevent control Value property to be above of it.